# Multiple color change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I need help making this Javascript change the color of the "I love George Brown" between the div, I got it to change the font color, and when i setup the change for the background color the only color that works is the same color as the font color. Please help, I need to do this in pure JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonrobert/tuEe6/

```
<html>
<body>
   
<script>
    function changeColor()
    {
        var newColor = document.getElementById('colorPicker').value;
        document.getElementById('colorMsg').style.color = newColor;
    }
    function changeBack()
    {
        var back = document.getElementById('colorPicker').value;    
        document.getElementById('colorMsg').style.background = back ;
    }    
</script>

<div id="colorMsg" style="font-size:50px; text-align:center; margin-bottom:200px;width:150px;height:100px;padding:5px;">I LOVE GEORGE BROWN</div>                                                                                         

<h2>Choose Font Color</h2>

<select id="colorPicker" onchange="JavaScript:changeColor()">
    <option value="transparent">None</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="salmon">Salmon</option>
    <option value="lightblue">Light Blue</option>
    <option value="limegreen">Lime Green</option>
    <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
    <option value="violet">Violet</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
<div id="colorMsg"></div>

<h2>Choose Background Color:</h2>

<select id="colorPicker" onchange="JavaScript:changeBack()">
    <option value="transparent">None</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="salmon">Salmon</option>
    <option value="lightblue">Light Blue</option>
    <option value="limegreen">Lime Green</option>
    <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
    <option value="violet">Violet</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use the same ID for both selects; that's invalid html, and is causing your code to fail.

Comment: Also, "backgroundColor", not just "background".

Comment: @Pointy Doesn't matter in this case. `background` is a shorthand that can accept color value.

Comment: @Pavlo It doesn't matter for actual functionality but for future reference setting using `backgroundColor` might make it more clear, if your pedantic that is :)

Comment: @Pavlo yes you're right. I keep breaking my rule of avoiding Stackoverflow until I've had some coffee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your selects have the same id value of `colorPicker`.  Try changing the second one to have a different id like below.

```
<h2>Choose Background Color:</h2>

<select id="colorPickerBackground" onchange="JavaScript:changeBack()">
  <option value="transparent">None</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="salmon">Salmon</option>
  <option value="lightblue">Light Blue</option>
  <option value="limegreen">Lime Green</option>
  <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
  <option value="violet">Violet</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Then in the js

```
function changeBack()
{

    var back = document.getElementById('colorPickerBackground').value;    

    document.getElementById('colorMsg').style.background = back ;

}
```

Comment: Thanks made the changes

Answer (score 3):

Using duplicate IDs is going to cause you trouble, which you seem to have discovered. Make sure you don't use the same ID twice. Here is my suggestion:

**<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuEe6/3/)</kbd>**

**HTML**

```
<select id="foregroundColorPicker" onchange="JavaScript:changeColor()">
    <option value="transparent">None</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="salmon">Salmon</option>
    <option value="lightblue">Light Blue</option>
    <option value="limegreen">Lime Green</option>
    <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
    <option value="violet">Violet</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>

<select id="backgroundColorPicker" onchange="JavaScript:changeBack()">
    <option value="transparent">None</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="salmon">Salmon</option>
    <option value="lightblue">Light Blue</option>
    <option value="limegreen">Lime Green</option>
    <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
    <option value="violet">Violet</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Your corresponding JS should reflect these changes:

**Javascript**

```
function changeColor(){
    var newColor = document.getElementById('foregroundColorPicker').value;
    document.getElementById('colorMsg').style.color = newColor;
}

function changeBack(){
    var back = document.getElementById('backgroundColorPicker').value;    
    document.getElementById('colorMsg').style.backgroundColor = back ;
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest changing `style.background` to be `style.backgroundColor` unless you need to change other parts of the background. Just for peoples understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tuEe6/1/)

```
function changeBack() {

var back = document.getElementById('colorPicker_back').value;
document.getElementById('colorMsg').style.background = back;
}
```

to chage the diffent id.

Answer (score 1):

You used the same id twice
An id is a **unique** identifier. It has to be unique in the document to work correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/tuEe6/4/

```
<!-- ... -->
<select id="colorPicker1" onchange="JavaScript:changeColor()">
<!-- ... -->
<select id="colorPicker2" onchange="JavaScript:changeBack()">
<!-- ... -->
```

---

```
// ...
var newColor = document.getElementById('colorPicker1').value;
// ...
var back = document.getElementById('colorPicker2').value;
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this

HTML for displaying a text and a button to select color

```
<span id="text">Hello World</span>
<input type="button" id="red" value="Red" />
```

JS to do the magic

```
(function() {
    var oText = document.getElementById('text');
    var oRed = document.getElementById('red');
    oRed.addEventListener('click', function() {
        oText.setAttribute('style', 'color: red');
        //oText.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: blue'); //In case of background color
    }, false);
})();
```

Extend this to your needs